# Convert and Append array to existing Key value

Tags: javascript

I have key:value pair as below :

```
const valueSelection = {
   name: string,
   colour: string,
   design: string,
   valueTag: string[],
}
```

during the run time it becomes as below

```
const valueSelection = {
   name: 'Sam',
   colour: 'blue',
   design: 'normal',
   valueTag: [1, 2]
}
```

want to convert this into as below

```
const valueSelection = {
   name: 'Sam',
   colour: 'blue',
   design: 'normal',
   valueTag1: 1,
   valueTag2: 2
}
```

How to do this in Reactjs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how is it related to `reactjs` ?

Comment: How does valueTag get populated? Is it updated once on the components rendering?

Comment: Yes its updated during the component rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
var newValue = {
     ...oldValue,
     valueTag: undefined,    
    ...(
        Object.fromEntries(
           oldValue.valueTag.map((val, index) => [`valueTag${index + 1}`, val])
        )
    )                
}
```

Comment: nice :thumbsup: